# Remove video and audio in insert media dropdown in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove all traces of video and audio in my wordpress post create. I manage to make my post create to accept images only but My problem is that when you go to medial library there is still an video and audio menu on the drop down list. Same goes to media tab. 
See the image below for clarifications.

[image: Remove video and audio in insert media dropdown in wordpress]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to functions.php

```
function my_remove_post_mime_types( $post_mime_types = array() ) {

    $rem_keys = array( "audio", "video" );

    $post_mime_types = array_diff_key( $post_mime_types, array_flip( $rem_keys ) );

    return $post_mime_types;

}
add_filter( 'post_mime_types', 'my_remove_post_mime_types' );
```

Unfortunately there isn't a documentation link I can point you to for further reading.